# Modifying the size of the cell of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to modify the size of the cells that the UICollectionview contains. I believe that the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` should do the trick. Yet nothing is happening.

I have looked into similar questions, they have advised doing the same thing. I am sort of suspicious of my inheritance.

The problem is that the cells remain in the same size regardless of the value they were fed in.

```
class HikeViewController: UIViewController {
    var test: Int?

    @IBOutlet weak var options: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        print(test!)

        options.dataSource = self
        options.delegate = self

    }



}

extension HikeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    //collectionCell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: 400, height: 500)
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }



}
```

And when I conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`the app termainates where I set the followings:

```
 options.dataSource = self
 options.delegate = self
```

And the error is:

`Could not cast value of type 'HikingClub.HikeViewController' (0x108e1f948) to 'UICollectionViewDataSource' (0x10e723ff0).`

It's worth adding that I have made sure of the connection between `HikeViewController` and the storyboard.

Comment: do you have dynamic cell sizing on in the collection view settings? Or something similar?

Comment: I do. I have updated the question.

Comment: it should be off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension HikeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

`}`

It should be something like this

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your extension a subclass of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`
2. Use the following function

   `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       // code
   }`

Comment: I have updated the question. as the app terminates where I set the delegate and datasource to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you implement the protocol UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your class declaration.

```
extension HikeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {}
```

also you have are not calling the delegate method, just defining a new one.

check the first parameter (collectionView -> _ collectionView)

func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollec

Comment: I have updated the question. as the app terminates where I set the delegate and datasource to itself.

Comment: Idk why ur having now this issue with delegate and datasource assigments, but your delegate method was not beign called on first place.